# Preciso de Ajuda um arquivo .Lua

Tags: lua

Venho recentemente "aprendendo" mecher com programação, porém sou bem leigo ainda. E recentemente desenvolvi um HUD aonde jogo, porém gostaria de mudar a **string.format** dele.

```
local function AddLoot(id, new)
    local newVal = new * GetValue(id)
    Looted = Looted + newVal

    local hud = LootedHUDs[id]
    if hud then
        hud.count = hud.count + new
        hud.hud:SetText(hud.count .." (".. GetValue(id) * hud.count .." gp)")
    else
        local hud = {}
        hud.count = new
        NewlyLooted = NewlyLooted + 1
        hud.posy = TotalLoot.posy
        hud.img = HUD.New(Hudx-5, hud.posy-5, id, textColor.r, textColor.g, textColor.b)
        hud.img:SetItemSize(10)
        hud.name = HUD.New(Hudx+30, hud.posy, Item.GetName(id), countColor.r, countColor.g, countColor.b)
        hud.hud = HUD.New(Hudx+165, hud.posy, new .." (".. newVal .." gp)", textColor.r, textColor.g, textColor.b)
        LootedHUDs[id] = hud
        
        TotalLoot.posy = TotalLoot.posy + 15
        TotalLoot.hud:SetPosition(Hudx + 80, TotalLoot.posy + 15)
        TotalLootTitle.hud:SetPosition(Hudx, TotalLoot.posy + 15)
    end
end
```

Essa parte [ **hud.hud = HUD.New(Hudx+165, hud.posy, new .." (".. newVal .." gp)", textColor.r, textColor.g, textColor.b)** ] é onde mostra o que foi contado, porem ele não separa as milhares. Por exemplo:

loot total:  1000000 gps <- assim que ele fica

loot total:  1.000.000 gps <- assim que quero que ele fique.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que usa regex para identificar cada 3 algarismos e insere um ponto entre eles para te auxiliar com isso, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```lua
local function addSeparators(number) -- Declaração da função, recebe um numero
    local k -- Variavel que indica em qual algarismo estamos

    repeat
        -- Regex que procura por vários numeros seguidos por 3 numeros e os separa em grupos
        -- Adiciona um '.' entre os grupos
        number, k = string.gsub(number, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", "%1.%2")
    until k == 0 -- Processou todos os algarismos

    return number -- Retorna a nova string processada
end
```

E então para usar no seu código:

```lua
local separatedVal = addSeparators(newVal)
hud.hud = HUD.New(Hudx+165, hud.posy, new .." (".. separatedVal .." gp)", textColor.r, textColor.g, textColor.b)
```

Comment: Francisco! Obrigado pela informação porém ao adicionar ele não está transformando o valor.

Comment: @Thanatos provavelmente você teria que alterar o if de cima tambem: `hud.hud:SetText(hud.count .." (".. addSeparators(GetValue(id) * hud.count) .." gp)")`

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo! Fiz o ajuste e foi!